# How to insert data from different multi select drop downs with same name in the Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, multidimensional-array, multi-select

Am  working on a form where one adds different buffet names plus the items that make up that buffet and the form includes several fields for adding the buffet names and also several multi select fields for selecting the buffet items but am finding an issue with adding that data into the database.

```
    <form>
<input name="buffet[]" type="text">
<select name="buffetitems[]">
<option value="item1">item1</option>
<option value="item2">item2</option>
<option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<input name="buffet[]" type="text">
<select name="buffetitems[]">`
<option value="item1">item1</option>
<option value="item2">item2</option>
<option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

so far i have the PHP code to add the buffetnames and i want to use the buffet_id as a foreign key in another table that will have the buffet items but am stuck on how to add the buffet items to the database with buffet_id as foreign key.

```
<?php
$buffet=$_POST['buffet'];
$buffetitems=$_POST['buffetitems'];
foreach($buffet as $buffet){
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO buffets(buffetname) VALUES('$buffet')");
$last_id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);

}
?>
```

That's what i have so far and challenge is in creating the "buffetitems" table where each item has the buffet_id as a foreign key like;

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO buffetitems(buffet_id,buffetname) VALUES('$last_id','$buffetname')");
```

Comment: Please show your PHP code (db insertion)

Comment: Ive added it please

Comment: `name="buffet[]` but `name="buffetitems[][]` then you should be able to loop over the relevant `buffet[]` occurance and its subordinate items without getting confused

Comment: Change the HTML and then just `print_r($buffet);` and also `print_r($buffetitems);` and you should see the way to process them both